# Personal Node on Server 2012 R2

Tags: full-node

I'd like to run a personal node on existing infrastructure, which already provides peer2site VPN connection. So I installed Monero GUI on the Server and synced blockchain. Now I want to connect to this "remote node", which only listens on localhost. Can I get the daemon to listen on the Windows Server's real IP instead of localhost. And if, would this setup work?
Can anyone provide instructions?

Thanks in advance

Bernie

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the Monero GUI, just run the monero daemon executable (it's called monerod).

The command line flags you should use are:

```
monerod.exe --rpc-bind-ip 111.222.333.444 --rpc-bind-port 18089 --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind
```

Replace 111.222.333.444 with the IP address of your externally facing network interface.